# table selection with CSS/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i  have a 5x5 grid and im using tables to do it and i am able to edit using css the first 5 the but cant do the rest.

Is there away i can change the colour of each individual cell. I need an empty square 11 black squares and 13 white squares.

I have been trying to use this but this only works up to to the td:nth-child(1)

```
    .box tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(1) {
     width: 60px;
          height: 60px;
          margin: 1px;
          text-align: center;
          background-color: black;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: x-large;
```

```js
var id_empty;
var num_moves;
var isCompleted = false;
var time=0;
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25];

window.addEventListener("load", startTimer, false);

function startTimer()
{
    window.setInterval("updateTime()", 1000);
} 

function updateTime()
{ 
    ++time;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML ="Current Time: " +time +" (seconds)";
} 

function startPuzzle() {
    num_moves = 0;
    isCompleted = false;

    for(var i=0; i < 25; i++) {
        var tmp = document.getElementById(i);
        tmp.className = "cell ";
    }

    randomNumber = nums.sort(function () { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);});
    while(!Problem.prototype.is_solvable(randomNumber)) {
        randomNumber = nums.sort(function () { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);});
    }

    for(var i=0; i < 25; i++) {
        var tmp = document.getElementById(i);
        if(randomNumber[i] == 25) {
            tmp.className = "cell empty";
            tmp.innerHTML = "";
            id_empty = i;
        }
        else
            tmp.innerHTML = randomNumber[i];
    }

}

function clickCell(x)
{
    if(isCompleted)
        return;

    if(x.id != id_empty+'') {
        var emptyI = Math.floor(id_empty/5);
        var emptyJ = id_empty % 5;
        var id_selected = Number(x.id);
        var selectedI = Math.floor(id_selected/5);
        var selectedJ = id_selected % 5;

        if((Math.abs(emptyI - selectedI) == 1 && emptyJ == selectedJ) ||
           (Math.abs(emptyJ - selectedJ) == 1 && emptyI == selectedI)) {

            document.getElementById(id_empty).className = "cell";
            document.getElementById(id_empty).innerHTML = x.innerHTML;
            
            x.className = "cell empty";
            x.innerHTML = '';
            
            id_empty = id_selected;
            num_moves++;

            document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = "Moves so far: " + num_moves;
            
            if(isDone()){
                isCompleted = true;
                document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = "Letter complete - Shuffle tiles" + num_moves;
            }
        }
    }
}

<!-- is done fuction can be used for letter recognition and is for future work -->

function isDone() {
    return document.getElementById('0').innerHTML == '1' &&
        document.getElementById('1').innerHTML == '2' &&
        document.getElementById('2').innerHTML == '3' &&
        document.getElementById('3').innerHTML == '4' &&
        document.getElementById('4').innerHTML == '5' &&
        document.getElementById('5').innerHTML == '6' &&
        document.getElementById('6').innerHTML == '7' &&
        document.getElementById('7').innerHTML == '8' &&
        document.getElementById('8').innerHTML == '9' &&
        document.getElementById('9').innerHTML == '10' &&
        document.getElementById('10').innerHTML == '11' &&
        document.getElementById('11').innerHTML == '12' &&
        document.getElementById('12').innerHTML == '13' &&
        document.getElementById('13').innerHTML == '14' &&
        document.getElementById('14').innerHTML == '15' &&
  document.getElementById('15').innerHTML == '16' &&
        document.getElementById('16').innerHTML == '17' &&
        document.getElementById('17').innerHTML == '18' &&
        document.getElementById('18').innerHTML == '19' &&
        document.getElementById('19').innerHTML == '20' &&
        document.getElementById('20').innerHTML == '21' &&
        document.getElementById('21').innerHTML == '22' &&
        document.getElementById('22').innerHTML == '23' &&
        document.getElementById('23').innerHTML == '24' &&
        document.getElementById('24').innerHTML == '25' ;
}


function lastClick() {
    var curr_state = currentState();
    var problem = new Problem(curr_state);
    var sol = Solver.a_star_search(problem);
    var result = "<ol>";
    for(var i = 0; i < sol.length; i++) {
        var n = moveNumb(sol[i],curr_state);
        curr_state = problem.result(sol[i],curr_state);
        result += "<li>move " + n + "</li>";
    }
    result += "</ol>";
    document.getElementById("steps").innerHTML = result;
}


function currentState() {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        var tmp = document.getElementById(String(i)).innerHTML;
        if(tmp == '') {
            result[i] = 25;
        }
        else {
            result[i] = Number(tmp);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function moveNumb(action,state) {
    var i = state.indexOf(25);
    switch(action) {
    case Action.up:
        return state[Util.index(Util.x(i),Util.y(i) - 1)];
    case Action.down:
        return state[Util.index(Util.x(i),Util.y(i) + 1)];
    case Action.right:
        return state[Util.index(Util.x(i) + 1,Util.y(i))];
    case Action.left:
        return state[Util.index(Util.x(i) - 1,Util.y(i))];
    }
}

Array.prototype.clone = function() { return this.slice(0); };
Array.prototype.swap = function(i1,i2) {
    var copy = this.clone();
    var tmp = copy[i1];
    copy[i1] = copy[i2];
    copy[i2] = tmp;
    return copy;
};


var Problem = function(start_state) {
    this.init_state = start_state;
    return this;
}

Problem.prototype.is_solvable = function(start) {
    start = start.clone();    start.splice(start.indexOf(25), 1);
    start[24] = 25;
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        if(start[i] != i+1) {
            count++;
            var j = start.indexOf(i+1);
            start[j] = start[i];
            start[i] = i+1;
        }
    }
    return count % 2 == 0;
}
```

```css
.box {
              border-style: solid;
              border-color: black;
              border-width: 5px;
              margin: 5px;
          }


          .cell {
              width: 60px;
              height: 60px;
              margin: 1px;
              text-align: center;
              background-color: black;
              font-weight: bold;
              font-size: x-large;
              padding: 0px;
          }

    
    .wCell {
              width: 60px;
              height: 60px;
              margin: 1px;
              text-align: center;
              background-color: white;
           text:white;
          font: black;
              font-weight: bold;
              font-size: x-large;
              padding: 0px;
          }
    
 

          
          .empty {
              background-color: white;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="puzzle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="startPuzzle()">
      <h2></h2>
      <p id="moves"></p>
      <p id="time"></p>
      <p>
      <button onclick="window.location.reload()">Shuffle Tiles</button>
      </p>
      <p>
      </p>
      <table class="box">
        <tr>
          <td id="0" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">1</td>
          <td id="1" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">2</td>
          <td id="2" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">3</td>
          <td id="3" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">4</td>
    <td id="4" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="5" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">6</td>
          <td id="6" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">7</td>
          <td id="7" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">8</td>
    <td id="8" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">9</td>
          <td id="9" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="10" class="wCell" onclick="clickCell(this)">11</td>
          <td id="11" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">12</td>
    <td id="12" class="wcell" onclick="clickCell(this)">13</td>
          <td id="13" class="wcell" onclick="clickCell(this)">14</td>
          <td id="14" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="15" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">16</td>
    <td id="16" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">17</td>
          <td id="17" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">18</td>
          <td id="18" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">19</td>
    <td id="19" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">20</td>
        </tr>
   <tr>
          <td id="20" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">21</td>
    <td id="21" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">22</td>
          <td id="22" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">23</td>
          <td id="23" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">24</td>
    <td id="24" class="cell" onclick="clickCell(this)">25</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *I need an empty square 11 black squares and 13 white squares* ... Does this have any pattern ? or just random ?

Comment: random just need an emty square 11 black squares and 13 white squares

Comment: I'm not a JS master but the logic can be, sort all `td` pick 11 random and set a class to be one color, then filter the elements with no class and pick one random to be empty ... As I said I'm not a JS vanilla master so here is a JQuery demo maybe you can use as the base logic https://jsfiddle.net/yw6nq2wu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hi your every cell has different id you can use the id to colour each cell differently.

#12{ background: green;}

Comment: Hi its because css does not like/accept the class and id names to start with number, i have two suggestion change the id from numbers #12 to #a12, #a1, etc and also u can more classes to force ur css ie:                           table tr #a12 {background:green;}

Answer (score 0):

In this Snippet:

1. Every `<td>` is collected into an array
2. Next an array of 25 strings representing 11 black, 13 white, and 1 transparent is shuffled.
3. Then the newly shuffled array of colors and the array of `<td>`s are merged by `.map()` method.
4. As the 2 arrays are being merged, each pair is ran through a switch. This switch will color each `<td>` background.
5. A new array is returned comprising of the colored pattern the table is displaying.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var x = 0,
  y = 0,
  temp = null;

// Collect every <td> into an array
const tiles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td'));

const colors = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 't'];

// Fisher-Yates Shuffle
for (x = colors.length - 1; x > 0; x -= 1) {
  y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x + 1));
  temp = colors[x];
  colors[x] = colors[y];
  colors[y] = temp;
}

console.log(colors);

// Map() both arrays into one
const mixArray = tiles.map(function(cell, idx) {
  [cell, colors[idx]];
  var cc = colors[idx];
  
  // Determine tile color
  switch (cc) {
    case 'b':
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      break;
    case 'w':
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      break;
    case 't':
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      break;
  }
  return cell;
});

console.log(mixArray);
```

```css
table { border:1px solid grey; table-layout:fixed;}
tbody {background:#555;}
td {border:1px solid red; width:50px;height:50px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='A'>
      <td class='A1'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='A2'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='A3'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='A4'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='A5'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='B'>
      <td class='B1'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='B2'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='B3'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='B4'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='B5'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='C'>
      <td class='C1'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='C2'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='C3'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='C4'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='C5'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='D'>
      <td class='D1'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='D2'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='D3'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='D4'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='D5'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='E'>
      <td class='E1'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='E2'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='E3'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='E4'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='E5'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```